# Thread synchronization issues of APUE

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm reading APUE and I am confused with thread synchronization of chapter 11. Below is a code snippet.

```
#define NHASH 29
#define HASH(fp) (((unsigned long)fp)%NHASH)

struct foo *fh[NHASH];

pthread_mutex_t hashlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct foo {
    int             f_count;
    pthread_mutex_t f_lock;
    struct foo     *f_next; /* protected by hashlock */
    int             f_id;
    /* ... more stuff here ... */
};

struct foo *
foo_alloc(void) /* allocate the object */
{
    struct foo  *fp;
    int         idx;

    if ((fp = malloc(sizeof(struct foo))) != NULL) {
        fp->f_count = 1;
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&fp->f_lock, NULL) != 0) {
            free(fp);
            return(NULL);
        }
        idx = HASH(fp);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&hashlock);
        fp->f_next = fh[idx];
        fh[idx] = fp;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashlock);
        /* ... continue initialization ... */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock);
    }
    return(fp);
}
```

My doubts are:

1. Why place `pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock)` before the `pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashlock)`? Could I place it afterward instead?
2. Since `fp` is local variable, could `pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock)` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock)` be removed all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, because the actions after the `pthread_mutex_lock(&hashlock)` expose the newly created structure to other threads by adding it to the the `fh` list.  While the hashlock is held, no-one can access the variable; as soon as the hashlock is released, it becomes accessible to other threads via the hash, but locking the `fp_>f_lock` mutex prevents anyone messing with `fp`.
2. Not with the code as written. If the whole structure was initialized except for the hashing, then you could do without locking the `fp->f_lock` mutex; just before completing, you'd lock the hashlock, hook the newly allocated item into the hash tables, and then release the hashlock, and you would be safe.  If you need any exclusive access after the structure is added into the hash table, you have to acquire its mutex.  The way it is written, that's a non-waiting acquisition of the mutex; there is no other process that could have access to the variable.

   ```
   if ((fp = malloc(sizeof(struct foo))) != NULL) {
       fp->f_count = 1;
       if (pthread_mutex_init(&fp->f_lock, NULL) != 0) {
           free(fp);
           return(NULL);
       }
       idx = HASH(fp);
       /* ... complete initialization except for adding to hash table ... */
       pthread_mutex_lock(&hashlock);
       fp->f_next = fh[idx];
       fh[idx] = fp;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashlock);
   }
   ```

So, there is logic behind what is done; it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there's a second thread that's looping through the created objects, doing something with them. In this case:

1. No, because the loop thread might access the newly created object before being initialized at all.
2. No, because the loop thread might access the newly created object being half initialized.